# Reference request: Article from The Economist

Tags: reference-request

In a 2012 article in *The Economist* entitled ["The half-life of facts"](https://www.economist.com/babbage/2012/11/28/the-half-life-of-facts), mathematician  Samuel Arbesman states that "two high-school students figured out a new way to prove one of Euclid's theorems, something that had not been done in a thousand years."

What theorem is he referring to? Who are these students? Is there a publication?

Comment: Is there a publication? Yes: the book which the author discusses on the linked page. *Samuel Arbesman, a mathematician at Harvard, calls this "The Half-life of Facts", the title of his new book. In it he explains . . .*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article in the New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/1999/03/07/nyregion/the-eternal-challenge-of-euclid-s-geometry.html), it's [Euclid Book VI, Proposition 10](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI10.html), and the article is

> "Euclid, Fibonacci, Sketchpad", Litchfield, Daniel C.; Goldenheim, David A.
>   *Mathematics Teacher*, v90 n1 p8-12 Jan 1997

(https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ538281)

It was reprinted in *Math Horizons*, https://doi.org/10.1080/10724117.1996.11974999.